# How to get matrix's job's name in the steps part of the yaml file?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pretty simple Azure Pipelines YAML file like:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'

strategy:
  matrix:
    debian:
      img: 'debian:latest'
    fedora:
      img: 'fedora:latest'
    arch:
      img: 'archlinux:latest'
    opensuse:
      img: 'opensuse/leap:latest'


container: $[ variables['img'] ]

steps:
  - script: printenv
    displayName: Dump env
  - script: make
    displayName: Build the project
```

Which does nothing more than building the same project on each of the four containers enlisted above.

It works, but I'd like to have also a step that uses the name of the job (debian, fedora, etc.) for running a special script.

How can I get access to the job's name in `steps`? Is there something like `$(job)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the [pre-defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) variable `$(Agent.JobName)` that you can use. for example:

```
steps:
  - script: echo $(Agent.JobName)
    displayName: echo $(Agent.JobName)
```

Will give this output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get this without 'Job'?

Comment: @EthanFischer this is the default :/ you can add a small script to remove it.

Comment: it seems you have one extra bracket in "displayName: echo $(Agent.JobName))"

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered a similar situation, I just created another matrix variable to solve the issue.

With your pipeline, it would look like

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'

strategy:
  matrix:
    debian:
      job: debian
      img: 'debian:latest'
    fedora:
      job: fedora
      img: 'fedora:latest'
    arch:
      job: arch
      img: 'archlinux:latest'
    opensuse:
      job: opensuse
      img: 'opensuse/leap:latest'


container: $(img)

steps:
  - script: printenv
    displayName: Dump env
  - script: make
    displayName: Build the project
  - script: echo $(job)
    displayName: echo $(job)
```